# wp_editor() renders outside wrapping div

Tags: editor

If have a plugin with a text box.  I wish to replace the text box with an editor.

My source code is

```
            <div id="editorwrap">
            <?php wp_editor("testing","the-editor"); ?>
            </div>
```

I expect that the editor will render within the `div` however here is the source code from the page.

The editor is right at the top of the `entry-content` div and my div is at the bottom of this sample.

```
<div class="entry-content">
        <div id="wp-the-editor-wrap" class="wp-core-ui wp-editor-wrap tmce-active"><link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='https://dev.speakout.123host.net.au/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=5.5.1' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='editor-buttons-css'  href='https://dev.speakout.123host.net.au/wp-includes/css/editor.min.css?ver=5.5.1' media='all' />
<div id="wp-the-editor-editor-tools" class="wp-editor-tools hide-if-no-js"><div class="wp-editor-tabs"><button type="button" id="the-editor-tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" data-wp-editor-id="the-editor">Visual</button>
<button type="button" id="the-editor-html" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html" data-wp-editor-id="the-editor">Text</button>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wp-the-editor-editor-container" class="wp-editor-container"><div id="qt_the-editor_toolbar" class="quicktags-toolbar"></div><textarea class="wp-editor-area" rows="20" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="the-editor" id="the-editor">testing</textarea></div>
</div>

<div id="editorwrap"></div>
```

What is the trick to getting the editor inside a div in a specific position on the page, rather than at the top?

**[UPDATE]** 3 years later and I have come back to this.  The result is the same and there is still nothing to be found when searching.  Perhaps there is more knowledge now and someone can answer.

Comment: If that's the raw HTML source as sent by the server ( on Chrome (Windows desktop), it's what you see when you press `Ctrl` + `U` ), then I don't know why so. But if that's the DOM source rendered by the browser, then it's possible a script on your page moved the editor outside it's initial wrapper. Either way, it could be caused by a plugin or custom code in the active theme.

Comment: @SallyCJ - yep, it is the ctrl-U HTML source code.  The call to wp_edit() is inside a plugin but the editor HTML code is displayed prior to the plugin, even though my wrapper is displayed within the plugin code where it should be.

Comment: Maybe it's a shortcode output issue, but it would only happen if you did something like `return '<div id="editorwrap">' . wp_editor() . '</div>'` - could there be such code in the plugin and is it your own plugin? Perhaps you can show some more code?

Comment: 3 years later, I am trying again :P

Comment: Well that's strange.. but have you tried the common troubleshooting like deactivating all plugins (except your own or the one in question)? Have you also tried running the code on the front-end, e.g. a Page at `example.com/sample-page/`, and did the same issue persist? Because whether back then or now in 2024 with WordPress v6.4.2, the same exact code worked just fine for me, so this is likely caused by a (custom code in a) plugin/theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rephrasing the search question I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624773/wp-editor-is-out-of-the-custom-meta-box-div-how-to-keep-wp-editor-in-the-div

Use the ob_start() and ob_get_contents().

There are two other functions you typically pair it with: ob_get_contents(), which basically gives you whatever has been "saved" to the buffer since it was turned on with ob_start(), and then ob_end_clean() or ob_flush()

So my example should look like this:

```
 ob_start();
         wp_editor($content, 'text', array(
            'wpautop' => true,
            'media_buttons' => false,
            'textarea_rows' => 5
            )
            );
         $output = ob_get_clean();

        echo '
        <div id="editorwrap">
            <?php echo $output; ?>
            </div>
';
```

which works.